# Can I send data from one MKR1000 to another MKR1000

Tags: communication, mkr1000

I want to simply send data from one MKR1000 to the other over wifi, both are connected to the same network, but sending the data is where I get stuck, I've looked through tuts everywhere but can't seem to find an answer.. can someone point me to a solution?

I've set up my devices using the tut https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Wifi101WiFiChatServer
but the devices don't communicate to each other they only take telnet from the host server(my laptops wifi hotspot)

Comment: You want *one* device as the server. The other needs to be a client that connects to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WiFiClient object wraps a TCP socket. A normal TCP socket is connected to IP address and port. WiFiServer starts a listening socket on a port. If server on listening socket is contacted by a remote client socket, it creates a local socket connected with the remote client socket on a free port and returns a WiFiClient object wrapping the socket. Everything you write or print to a WiFiClient is send to that one remote socket.

If one of your client boards creates a WiFiClient and connects it to IP address and port of the WiFiServer on your 'server' board, then you get there a WiFiClient from server.available() and this two WiFiClient objects are connected. What you write/print on one side you read only from the WiFiClient object on the other side.

client socket

```
if (client.connect(serverIP, PORT)) {
  client.print("request\n");
  String response = client.readStringUntil('\n');
  Serial.println(response);
  client.stop();
}
```

server side

```
WiFiClient client = server.available();
if (client && client.connected()) {
  String request = client.readStringUntil('\n');
  Serial.println(request);
  client.print("response\n");
  client.stop();
}
```

Comment: You led me to a good tut, sometimes the right google search helps, thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

I found a tutorial that explains exactly what [Majenko](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/4143/majenko) and [Juraj](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/37622/juraj) explained,
https://www.instructables.com/id/MKR1000-IoT-Clientserver-Communications/

the library code that the tutorial references is useful, the tutorial is useful to us learning communication